# Context Menu Registry Entry Command

Tags: registry, contextmenu

I have a Batch file which archives all folders in a directory using the **7-Zip** Command line utility.

Here is the batch file if you would like to test it out

```
@echo
cmd.exe /c for /D %%d in (*.*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z -r "%%d.7z" "%%d"
pause
```

This is a very useful script for me HOWEVER it is rather time consuming having to copy the batch file into the directory every time I wish to do this.

I was hoping that I could add a context menu entry (like the "**Open Command Prompt here**" or "**TakeOwnership**") which would allow me to right click a directory and run this command:

`for /D %%d in (*.*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z "%d.7z" "%d`

I have had trouble with the registry key command syntax, and have thus been unable to successfully implement this into the context menu.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#shortcut_add_commands

It might help a bit, but I dont think it is going to the direction you want to.

I'm also trying to add something to the context menu, and it needs to give an argument to the program being called.

In that article, it does show applications taking arguments, but it puts the registry data in a (for me, third) part of the registry. I wouldnt be so hesitant against this, but the example I am following (Notepad++) doesnt have any entry here, so...

If I find out anything new, I'll drag it over here.